# Foundation range slider breaking when using javascript to set_value

Tags: jquery, slider, zurb-foundation

I have 2 range sliders on the same page.  One of them is contained within a hidden div.  When I use javascript to set the value of the 1st slider, the second slider is broken and does not drag correctly.  See code below.  To reproduce the issue

1. click 'hide next div' (this hides the 2nd slider)
2. click 'set slider 1 to 0'
3. click 'show next div' (this shows the 2nd slider)
4. attempt to drag slider 2

Code Pen demo:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/btalk

html

```
<div id="slider1" class="range-slider" data-slider data-options="step: 1;">
  <span class="range-slider-handle"></span>
  <span class="range-slider-active-segment"></span>
  <input type="hidden">
</div>

<button id="setZeroButton">set slider 1 to 0</button>
<button id="showButton">show next div</button>
<button id="hideButton">hide next div</button>

<div id="hidden-container">
 <div id="slider2" class="range-slider" data-slider data-options="step: 1;">
  <span class="range-slider-handle"></span>
  <span class="range-slider-active-segment"></span>
  <input type="hidden">
 </div>
</div>
```

js

```
$(document).foundation();

$('#setZeroButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#slider1').foundation('slider','set_value',0);
});
$('#showButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#hidden-container').show();
});

$('#hideButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#hidden-container').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that the sizing calculations for `#slider2` get messed up when it's hidden and re-shown. It seems to resolve the issue to initialize the slider again on show:

```
$('#showButton').on('click', function() {
    $('#hidden-container').show();
    $('#slider2').foundation('slider','set_value',0);
});
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kyunr

To avoid strangeness with the show button, you might simplify things: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/klivD